# Google apps script: How to send json to HTMLService

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I just started using GAS and I'm trying to send a SOQL query result into the HTML Service template to display in a table, but nothing shows up at all. Here's what I have so far:

display.html:

```
<div id = "main">
    <? var data = getData() ?>
    <p><? data ?></p>
</div>
```

code.gs:

```
function getData()
{
  var result = runSOQL(QUERY);
  Logger.clear();
  Logger.log(result);
  return JSON.stringify(result);
}
function displayData()
{
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('display').evaluate());
}
```

Query results in logger (only first result is shown):

> {"totalSize":1000,"done":true,"list":[{"types":{"type":"atype","url":"/media/img/"},"Id":"123abc","Name":"EL","Owner":{"types":{"type":"Name","url":"/media/mov"},"Id":"abc123","Name":"E r"},"LastModifiedDate":"2015-03-06T10:23:25.000+0000","Id__c":"ffff"},

Answer (score 0):

Solved in display.html I had a syntax. Here is the correction:

```
<p><?= data ?></p>
```